# How limit the text node to a few variants?

Tags: relaxng

Say, I have the tag "fruit", which can be "banana" and "apple" only, not any text, like so:

```
<fruit>banana</fruit>
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<fruit>potato</fruit> <!-- wrong! -->
```

If I set `<text/>`, it will allow any text...
How do I make a more strict Relax NG entry for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://relaxng.org/tutorial-20011203.html#IDAVXYR. So instead of

```
<element name="fruit">
  <text/>
</element>
```

use

```
<element name="fruit">
  <choice>
    <value>banana</value>
    <value>apple</value>
  </choice>
</element>
```

For a real life example in RELAX NG Compact syntax, see https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/blob/262af55030bd3f5b389d1b327b2e725d83da34c8/csl-repository.rnc#L89:

```
element cs:rights {
  "This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License"
}
```

which only validates `<rights>This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License</rights>`.